# Difference between iterating through a generator and converting to a list

Tags: python

I would have expected these two pieces of code to produce the same results

```
from itertools import groupby

for i in list(groupby('aaaabb')):
    print i[0], list(i[1])

for i, j in groupby('aaaabb'):
    print i, list(j)
```

In one I convert the iterator returned by groupby to a list and iterate over that, and in the other I iterate over the returned iterator directly.

The output of this script is

```
a []
b ['b']


a ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
b ['b', 'b']
```

Why is this the case?

**Edit:** for reference, the result of `groupby('aabbaa')` looks like

```
('a', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10c1324d0>)
('b', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10c132250>)
```

Comment: You can do `for i,j in list(groupby('aabbaa')):`. The difference is that the first creates a list of all the elements in the iterator, which may be very big and RAM-intensive.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo But why the difference in output?

Comment: That actually doesn't work correctly (i.e. it produces the same results as the first loop), although I would have expected it to. Same issue.

Comment: My guess would be that the `groupby` object only holds a reference to the current group, and discards all previously generated ones.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the input should be sorted first.

Comment: @PeterWood Sorted input produces the same results.

Comment: @Jephron Not for me it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterWood updated original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quirk of the `groupby` function, presumably for performance.

From the [`itertools.groupby` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`. Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:
>
> ```
> groups = []
> uniquekeys = []
> data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
> for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
>     groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
>     uniquekeys.append(k)
> ```

So, you can do this:

```
for i in [x, list(y) for x, y in groupby('aabbaa')]:
    print i[0], i[1]
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to `map` `list` over the return value of `groupby`. Does this quirk rule that method out?

Comment: I wouldn't use `map()` in Python, because list comprehensions are easier to read.  However, if you want to use `map()`, by all means, go ahead.  Were you thinking of something like `map(labmda x: x[0], list(x[1]), groupby('aabbaa'))`? Because that is equivalent to `[x, list(y) for x, y in groupby('aabbaa')]`.